# Falta de memória em Java mesmo o computador tendo memória disponível

Tags: java, memória, jvm

A Java Virtual Machine "JVM" pode ficar sem memória mesmo se a máquina física tiver memória disponível?

Comment: Pode. Quando dá por exemplo um `OutOfMemoryError` em um programa Java é porque a JVM não conseguiu alocar memória, mesmo havendo mais memória disponível na máquina hospedeira. Existem configurações de inicialização para dizer à JVM quanto de memória ela será capaz de alocar no total.

Comment: Internamente a JVM é [dividida em várias áreas de memória](https://dzone.com/articles/java-memory-management) e o tamanho de cada uma pode ser configurado. E como essas áreas tem limites de tamanho próprios, elas podem estourar, mesmo que o servidor tenha mais memória disponível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que você esteja recebendo erro de falta de memória. Isto não quer dizer que toda memória foi ocupada mas sim que não teve como fazer alocação. Mesmo com GC existe alguma fragmentação e existem alguns padrões que o *garbage collector* usa que pode precisar alocar algo de uma certa forma que não é possível, ainda que para o que precisaria seria.

Em alguns casos uma das partes pode sofrer exaustão mesmo que tenha espaço em outras. O *heap* não é uma área única. Inclusive tem casos que o problema pode ser na memória não gerenciada que pode reportar algo anormal.

Além disto pode estar pedindo para alocar um objeto muito grande, para ele não tem espaço, mas ainda tem muito espaço disponível para outros objetos um pouco menores.

Então erro de falta de memória não significa que toda memória foi consumida, apenas que não não foi possível alocar o que foi pedido, por diversas razões.

Answer (score 2):

Pode sim, a JVM não utiliza toda a memória disponível na máquina, ela inicialmente é limitada, podendo ocasionar erros como OutOfMemory. Para solucionar esse tipo de problema, você pode, ao iniciar a aplicação, definir a memória que será utilizada pela JVM passando parâmetros como -Xms, -Xmx, entre outros.

Answer (score 0):

A JVM trabalha com uma mentalidade de segmentação de memória, onde existem subdivisões bem específicas cada uma voltada para certa finalidade.

- **Heap Memory:** Usado para armazenar os objetos que você aloca. Aqui você pode configurar as mesmas usando as flags **-Xms** (Tamanho inicial) e **-Xmx** (Tamanho máximo)
- **Non-Heap Memory:** Usado para meta-dados e outros (Classes que foram alocadas,informações de campos/métodos, constantes...). Também configurável pela flag "**-XX:MaxPermSize**"
- E a memória alocada para a própria JVM, afinal ela deve existir em algum lugar :^)

Aqui faz-se necessário distinguir a memória **alocada** para JVM da memória **usada** pelo seu programa. Caso, a memória **usada** tenda a querer passar a memória **alocada**, isso virá a gerar uma exceção (O famoso OutofMemory). É aqui que entrará a sua estratégia de programação para minimizar o desperdício de recursos e otimizar o ciclo de vida dos objetos que estão sendo usados.